How can i create a mat-table with multiple levels nested rows Angular 12 Node 14.15.0
I'm working on an Angular project and I need to create a table that can display data with multiple levels of nested rows. I have a dataset with hierarchical data that includes several levels of nesting, and I want to be able to expand and collapse rows to view details at each level.
Here's an example of my dataset structure:
const data = [
  {
    "idContinente_N1": "1", "nomContinente_N1": "America", "detalle":
      [
        {
          "idPais_N2": "1", "nomPais_N2": "Argentina", "detalle":
            [
              { "idEstado_N3": "1", "nomEstado_N3": "Buenos Aires" },
              {
                "idEstado_N3": "2", "nomEstado_N3": "Cordoba", "detalle":
                  [
                    { "idMunicipio_N4": "1", "nomMunicipio_N4": "Capital" },
                    { "idMunicipio_N4": "2", "nomMunicipio_N4": "Rio Cuarto" }
                  ]
              }
            ]
        },
        {
          "idPais_N2": "2", "nomPais_N2": "Brasil", "detalle":
            [
              { "idEstado_N3": "1", "nomEstado_N3": "Sao Paulo" },
              { "idEstado_N3": "2", "nomEstado_N3": "Rio de Janeiro" }
            ]
        },
        { "idPais_N2": "3", "nomPais_N2": "Chile" },
        {
          "idPais_N2": "4", "nomPais_N2": "Mexico", "detalle":
            [
              {
                "idEstado_N3": "1", "nomEstado_N3": "Ciudad de Mexico", "detalle":
                  [
                    {
                      "idMunicipio_N4": "1", "nomMunicipio_N4": "Benito Juarez", "detalle":
                        [
                          { "idColonia_N5": "1", "nomColonia_N5": "Napoles" },
                          {
                            "idColonia_N5": "2", "nomColonia_N5": "Del Valle", "detalle":
                              [
                                { "idCalle_N6": "1", "nomCalle_N6": "Calle 1" },
                                { "idCalle_N6": "2", "nomCalle_N6": "Calle 2" }
                              ]
                          }
                        ]
                    },
                    { "idMunicipio_N4": "2", "nomMunicipio_N4": "Coyoacan" }
                  ]
              },
              { "idEstado_N3": "2", "nomEstado_N3": "Nuevo Leon" }
            ]
        },
        { "idPais_N2": "5", "nomPais_N2": "Peru" },
        {
          "idPais_N2": "6", "nomPais_N2": "Uruguay", "detalle":
            [
              { "idEstado_N3": "1", "nomEstado_N3": "Montevideo" }
            ]
        },
        { "idPais_N2": "7", "nomPais_N2": "Paraguay" }
      ]
  },

  {
    "idContinente_N1": "2", "nomContinente_N1": "Europa", "detalle":
      [
        { "idPais_N2": "1", "nomPais_N2": "España" },
        {
          "idPais_N2": "2", "nomPais_N2": "Francia", "detalle":
            [
              {
                "idEstado_N3": "1", "nomEstado_N3": "Paris", "detalle":
                  [
                    { "idMunicipio_N4": "1", "nomMunicipio_N4": "Municipio 1" },
                    { "idMunicipio_N4": "2", "nomMunicipio_N4": "Municipio 2" }
                  ]
              },
              { "idEstado_N3": "2", "nomEstado_N3": "Lyon" }
            ]
        },
        { "idPais_N2": "3", "nomPais_N2": "Italia" },
        {
          "idPais_N2": "4", "nomPais_N2": "Alemania", "detalle":
            [
              {
                "idEstado_N3": "1", "nomEstado_N3": "Berlin", "detalle":
                  [
                    {
                      "idMunicipio_N4": "1", "nomMunicipio_N4": "Mitte", "detalle":
                        [
                          { "idColonia_N5": "1", "nomColonia_N5": "Napoles" },
                          { "idColonia_N5": "2", "nomColonia_N5": "Del Valle" },
                          { "idColonia_N5": "3", "nomColonia_N5": "Polanco" },
                        ]
                    },
                    { "idMunicipio_N4": "2", "nomMunicipio_N4": "Prenzlauer Berg" }
                  ]
              },
              { "idEstado_N3": "2", "nomEstado_N3": "Hamburgo" }
            ]
        },
        {
          "idPais_N2": "5", "nomPais_N2": "Portugal", "detalle":
            [
              { "idEstado_N3": "1", "nomEstado_N3": "Lisboa" }
            ]
        }
      ]
  }
];

I'm currently using Angular and Angular Material. I want to achieve a table where rows can be expanded to reveal more details, and this should work for multiple levels of nesting (like Continent > Country > State > Municipality).
Here is the current code I'm using:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';



const data = [   ];

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-table-test',
  templateUrl: './table-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-test.component.css']
})
export class TableTestComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
  displayedColumns: string[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    const transformedData = this.flattenData(data);
    this.dataSource.data = transformedData;

    console.log(transformedData);

    // Obtener todas las claves de todas las filas transformadas
    const allKeys = new Set<string>();
    transformedData.forEach(item => {
      Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
        allKeys.add(key.replace(/detalle\./g, ''));
      });
    });

    // Filtrar para no incluir el 'level' como columna
    this.displayedColumns = Array.from(allKeys).filter(key => key !== 'level');
  }

  flattenData(data: any[], parentKeys: string[] = []): any[] {
    let flattenedData: any[] = [];

    data.forEach(item => {
      const currentLevelData: any = {};
      const keys = Object.keys(item);
      let hasNestedData = false;

      // Recorrer cada clave del objeto
      keys.forEach(key => {
        if (Array.isArray(item[key])) {
          hasNestedData = true; // Marca que este nivel tiene datos anidados
          const nestedData = this.flattenData(item[key], [...parentKeys, key]);
          flattenedData.push(currentLevelData); // Agrega el nivel actual antes de los anidados
          flattenedData.push(...nestedData); // Agrega los datos anidados
        } else if (typeof item[key] === 'object' && item[key] !== null) {
          hasNestedData = true;
          const nestedObject = this.flattenData([item[key]], [...parentKeys, key]);
          flattenedData.push(currentLevelData);
          flattenedData.push(...nestedObject);
        } else {
          const newKey = [...parentKeys, key].join('_').replace(/detalle_/g, '');
          currentLevelData[newKey] = item[key];
        }
      });

      // Solo agrega el nivel actual si no tiene datos anidados
      if (!hasNestedData) {
        flattenedData.push(currentLevelData);
      }
    });

    return flattenedData;
  } 

}

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns" [matColumnDef]="column">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ column | titlecase }} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <span [ngStyle]="{'padding-left.px': element['level'] * 2}">{{ element[column] }}</span>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

.mat-cell, .mat-header-cell {
  padding: 4px; 
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

table.mat-table {
  border-collapse: separate;
} 

I'm having trouble implementing this feature and would appreciate any guidance on how to accomplish this. Specifically, I'm interested in:
How to handle the data transformation to support multiple levels of nesting.
How to implement the expandable rows for each level in Angular Material.
Any tips or best practices for managing the complexity of deeply nested data in a table.
Thank you!
This Angular component, TableTestComponent, is designed to display hierarchical data in a table format using Angular Material's MatTableDataSource.
dataSource: An instance of MatTableDataSource, which holds the data to be displayed in the table.
displayedColumns: An array of strings that represents the columns to be displayed in the table.
ngOnInit Method:
This lifecycle hook is executed when the component is initialized.
It starts by flattening the hierarchical data using the flattenData method.
The flattened data is then assigned to the dataSource for display in the table.
The method also extracts all unique keys from the transformed data and updates displayedColumns to include these keys, filtering out the 'level' key.
flattenData Method:
This method recursively processes the hierarchical data to flatten it into a format suitable for table display.
It traverses each item in the data array, collecting keys and values.
For each key, if the value is an array or an object, it recursively flattens the nested data.
Keys are concatenated with underscores and cleaned of the 'detalle_' prefix.
Flattened data is collected and returned as an array of objects, each representing a row in the table.
Overall, this component converts complex, nested data structures into a flat format that can be easily rendered in an Angular Material table, allowing for dynamic column generation based on the data structure.
